# RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant import loop

Tags: python, django

I have my models.py file import an external function which then writes to a specific model. I think this is some sort of import loop but I'm not sure.

This is a partial traceback

```
File "path/Directory/Package/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from externalFunction import myFunction
  File "path/Directory/externalFunction.py", line 9, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/myEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/path/anaconda3/envs/Brew/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

File structure

```
>Directory
    manage.py
    externalFunction.py
    >Package
        models.py
    >Package_api
        wsgi.py
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from externalFunction import myFunction

class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        default="name")
@receiver(post_save, sender=Job, dispatch_uid="run function")
def run_function(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    someOtherFunction()
    myFunction()
```

`externalFunction.py`

```
import django
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Package_api.settings')
django.setup()
from Package.models import Job

def myFunction():
    some stuff
```

I've tried removing `django.setup()` from externalFunction.py but then it cannot import Job from the models.